# Python cursor how do I replace with a string and maintain quotation marks in a SQL que?y

Tags: python, sql, django, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm using django. I'm having trouble replacing the email string in the query. It needs quotations around it since it compares strings.
I've tried using parameters on the execute function but that did not work:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT password,id FROM account WHERE email = %(mail)s", {'mail': userEmail})
```

I get a DatabaseError at /
ORA-00936: missing expression

```
q = "SELECT password,id from account WHERE email = '%s'" % userEmail
cursor.execute(q)
```

This produces a correct SQL query with the quotations. But I've heard this is a bad idea due to sql injection. Regardless, I'm getting a ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended error when I did this.

Comment: Use a bind variable.  There are plenty of examples in the cx_Oracle documentation: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try using f-string

```
query = f"SELECT password,id FROM account WHERE email='{userEmail}'"
```

Comment: I seem to still be getting the SQL command not properly ended error. It seems to happen after the query is executed. I'm no longer sure if it's even the query that's causing the problem now.

Comment: Please do not do string concatenation or interpolation like `'{userEmail}'` because it (1) is a security risk for SQL injection attacks (2) can give poor performance or scalability.  Instead use bind variables.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Christopher Jones, use a bind variable. This eliminates concerns about SQL injection, improves performance and removes the concerns about proper quoting. Your example should look like this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT password,id FROM account WHERE email = :mail",
               mail=userEmail)
```